# Excesivelly long single words forcing html table to stretch

Tags: css, html-table

I'm going to jump straight to the point with giving you the example fiddle,  the problem will make itself clear. Instructions: click on the paragraph in order to change its textual content (via javascript) and then input something a bit longer (like 150+ chars) but as a single word. For example, replace the initial content with a text like `LONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXT`... etc and you'll see the table stretches in a very strange way, although I've set max width and height for my paragraph and made overflow scrollable. I'd like to know what's causing that and what would be the best way to prevent it. Thanks in advance!
https://jsfiddle.net/aekjguj2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph needs one more thing: `word-break: break-all`.

```
<p id="description_changer" class="clickEdit" 
    style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100px; 
        overflow-y: scroll; word-break: break-all;">
    Click to dynamically replace me with a long single word content
</p>
```